# Select html tag with multiple css beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup for extracting tags form html. There are some html tag having multiple css classes example :

```
html = '''
         <a class ='a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal'>This is a anchor text</a>
         <div class ='s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal'>Div text</div>
       '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
all_prod_links = soup.find_all('a', {'class': ['a-link-normal','s-access-detail-page','s-color-twister-title-link','a-text-normal']})
```

when I am using above code it is giving me both the tags. Is there any way by which I can get the element containing all the css.

Answer (score 0):

This will find all tags (a, div, or other) that have 'class' attribute and have all the specified classes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
         <a class='a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal'>This is a anchor text</a>
         <div class='s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal'>Div text</div>
       '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
all_prod_links = soup.find_all(
    lambda t: 'class' in t.attrs and 'a-link-normal' in t['class'] and \
                       's-access-detail-page' in t['class'] and \
                       's-color-twister-title-link' in t['class'] and \
                       'a-text-normal' in t['class'])

print(all_prod_links)
```

Prints:

```
[<a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal">This is a anchor text</a>]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html = '''
         <a class ='a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal'>This is a anchor text</a>
         <div class ='s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal'>Div text</div>
       '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
all_prod_links = soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal'})
```

Result is

```
[<a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal">This is a anchor text</a>]
```